# Draw a cube and a pyramid

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm learning OpenGL and I'm using Qt 5.12. I currently need to draw a cube and a pyramid with triangles.

I think the vertex class and the triangle structure are fine but unfortunately not all the triangles are shown correctly. I'm still new to OpenGL so I'm probably missing something in the VBO/VAO binding section but I can't figure what.

I've created a myVertex class with 6 floats: 3 for position and 3 for color:

```
class myVertex{
public:
    GLfloat _x;
    GLfloat _y;
    GLfloat _z;
    GLfloat _r;
    GLfloat _g;
    GLfloat _b;

    myVertex(GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z, GLfloat r, GLfloat g, GLfloat b){
        _x=x;
        _y=y;
        _z=z;
        _r=r;
        _g=g;
        _b=b;

    }
};
```

Then I defined a structure for the triangles:

```
struct triangle {
    myVertex a;
    myVertex b;
    myVertex c;
};
```

In MainView::initializeGL() I define color and position in 3D of every vertex and then I build the triangles:

```
// Cube
    myVertex CUBE_LEFT_FRONT_DOWN  = myVertex(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    myVertex CUBE_RIGHT_FRONT_DOWN = myVertex( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    myVertex CUBE_LEFT_BACK_DOWN   = myVertex(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    myVertex CUBE_RIGHT_BACK_DOWN  = myVertex( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    myVertex CUBE_LEFT_FRONT_UP    = myVertex(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    myVertex CUBE_RIGHT_FRONT_UP   = myVertex( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    myVertex CUBE_LEFT_BACK_UP     = myVertex(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,0.2f,0.5f,0.7f);
    myVertex CUBE_RIGHT_BACK_UP    = myVertex( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,0.7f,0.2f,0.5f);


    // Every face is made of 2 triangles
    triangle left1  = {CUBE_LEFT_BACK_DOWN,  CUBE_LEFT_FRONT_DOWN,  CUBE_LEFT_BACK_UP};
    triangle left2  = {CUBE_LEFT_FRONT_UP,   CUBE_LEFT_FRONT_DOWN,  CUBE_LEFT_BACK_UP};
    triangle right1 = {CUBE_RIGHT_BACK_DOWN, CUBE_RIGHT_BACK_UP,    CUBE_RIGHT_FRONT_DOWN};
    triangle right2 = {CUBE_RIGHT_FRONT_UP,  CUBE_RIGHT_BACK_UP,    CUBE_RIGHT_FRONT_DOWN};
    triangle back1  = {CUBE_LEFT_BACK_DOWN,  CUBE_RIGHT_BACK_DOWN,  CUBE_LEFT_BACK_UP};
    triangle back2  = {CUBE_RIGHT_BACK_UP,   CUBE_RIGHT_BACK_DOWN,  CUBE_LEFT_BACK_UP};
    triangle front1 = {CUBE_LEFT_FRONT_DOWN, CUBE_RIGHT_FRONT_DOWN, CUBE_LEFT_FRONT_UP};
    triangle front2 = {CUBE_RIGHT_FRONT_UP,  CUBE_RIGHT_FRONT_DOWN, CUBE_LEFT_FRONT_UP};
    triangle down1  = {CUBE_LEFT_FRONT_DOWN, CUBE_RIGHT_FRONT_DOWN, CUBE_LEFT_BACK_DOWN};
    triangle down2  = {CUBE_RIGHT_BACK_DOWN, CUBE_RIGHT_FRONT_DOWN, CUBE_LEFT_BACK_DOWN};
    triangle up1    = {CUBE_RIGHT_BACK_UP,   CUBE_RIGHT_FRONT_UP,   CUBE_LEFT_BACK_UP};
    triangle up2    = {CUBE_LEFT_FRONT_UP,   CUBE_RIGHT_FRONT_UP,   CUBE_LEFT_BACK_UP};

    triangle cube[] = {left1, left2, right1, right2, back1, back2, front1, front2, down1, down2, up1, up2};


// Pyramid
    myVertex PYR_LEFT_FRONT  = myVertex(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    myVertex PYR_RIGHT_FRONT = myVertex( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
    myVertex PYR_LEFT_BACK   = myVertex(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    myVertex PYR_RIGHT_BACK  = myVertex( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f,0.5f,0.8f,0.0f);
    myVertex PYR_TOP         = myVertex( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,0.3f,0.1f,0.4f);


// Base need 2 triangles
    triangle leftside  = {PYR_LEFT_FRONT,  PYR_LEFT_BACK,   PYR_TOP};
    triangle rightside = {PYR_RIGHT_FRONT, PYR_RIGHT_BACK,  PYR_TOP};
    triangle frontside = {PYR_LEFT_FRONT,  PYR_RIGHT_FRONT, PYR_TOP};
    triangle backside  = {PYR_LEFT_BACK,   PYR_RIGHT_BACK,  PYR_TOP};
    triangle base1     = {PYR_LEFT_FRONT,  PYR_LEFT_BACK,   PYR_RIGHT_FRONT};
    triangle base2     = {PYR_RIGHT_BACK,  PYR_LEFT_BACK,   PYR_RIGHT_FRONT};

    triangle pyramid[] = {leftside, rightside, frontside, backside, base1, base2};
```

Now I define VBOs and VAOs, enable attributes, etc. :

```
GLuint cubeVBO;
GLuint cubeVAO;
GLuint pyrVBO;
GLuint pyrVAO;

glGenBuffers(1, &cubeVBO);
glGenVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cube), cube, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &pyrVBO);
glGenVertexArrays(1, &pyrVAO);
glBindVertexArray(pyrVAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pyrVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pyramid), pyramid, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(myVertex),(void *)0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(myVertex),(void *)(3*sizeof(GLfloat)));
```

And finally I draw to the screen:

```
MainView::paintGL() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    shaderProgram.bind();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVBO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,36);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pyrVBO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,18);


    shaderProgram.release();
}
```

I expected to see a figure like this:
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwbmK.jpg)

But right now I see this:
[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dDwx.jpg)

I reviewed the code many times but I can't understand what's going wrong.

Comment: If you use supported image formats I will be happy to make them visible for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a non-zero named array buffer object is bound, then the last parameter of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store.
The definition of the generic vertex attribute data and the name of the referenced buffer is sored in the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object)s state vector.

Before the array of generic vertex attribute data is defined, by the call of `glVertexAttribPointer`, the vertex array object, where the vertex specification should be stored to, has to be bound. The proper buffer object has to be bound, too:

```cpp
// vertex array buffer for cube
GLuint cubeVBO;
glGenBuffers(1, &cubeVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cube), cube, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// vertex array buffer for pyramid
GLuint pyrVBO;
glGenBuffers(1, &pyrVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pyrVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pyramid), pyramid, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

```cpp
// vertex array object for cube
GLuint cubeVAO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(myVertex),(void *)0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(myVertex),(void *)(3*sizeof(GLfloat)));

// vertex array object for pyramid
GLuint pyrVAO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &pyrVAO);
glBindVertexArray(pyrVAO);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pyrVBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(myVertex),(void *)0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,sizeof(myVertex),(void *)(3*sizeof(GLfloat)));
```